# How do I prevent inappropriate ads from appearing in my game?

Tags: unity, advertisements, content-rating, unity-ads

My game implements Unity ads, and is designed with a universal audience in mind. As such, I would prefer not to have 18+ ads (or even 13+ ads depending on the circumstances) appearing in it, especially since it would appeal to younger audiences as well. My question is then, how do I prevent age-inappropriate ads from appearing? Is there a way to simply set the age limit or content restrictions on Unity ads? The only setting along those lines that I can find is the COPPA toggle, and that would cause other issues (not to mention that it wouldn't do anything to the ads). I've looked in the dashboard for a while, and I've tried to research it beforehand, but the fact that they've shifted to a [centralized services page](https://operate.dashboard.unity3d.com), redirected all the old links (breaking them in the process), reorganized the settings in the dashboard, and 404d [their FAQ post on the topic](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/resources/dashboard-guide#ad-content-filters) doesn't help either. Blocking ads based on a rating would work too, as I would have to get one because I am publishing to Google Play.

Edit: The second link only 404s some of the time. I just happened to get it every time before asking this question. Bad luck, I guess.

Comment: The link seems to work fine for me. Under "Ad Filtering", there should be an "Exclude Content" section.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too now. It 404s pretty frequently though. I guess I just happened to show up right when it decided to have an error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unity ads can't contain adult material:

https://unity3d.com/legal/advertising-content-policy

> Advertising containing, linking or relating to content, goods or services in any of the following categories are prohibited by Unity Ads and may not be disseminated in any form via the Unity Ads Platform.
> [...]
>
> ### Adult
>
> Content that is sexually suggestive or that depicts, contains or provides access to pornography, nudity or other adult or risqué material, including content promoting adult-themed products.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Excessive violence
>
> Content that depicts or contains excessive violence or mutilation or that glorifies human suffering, death, self-harm or violence against animals.
>
> ### Gambling
>
> Content promoting any form of gambling or lottery to users where it is illegal or where any related required government license is not in place.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Tobacco/Vaping
>
> Content that promotes any form of tobacco or nicotine-related products, including vaping and electronic cigarettes.

These categories are what are usually seen as 13+, but for a full list, visit the site

Comment: I wonder if it's deliberate that they omitted alcohol from the list.

Comment: @kasperd Alcohol advertising isn't regulated all that much, compared to all the others. Think about the ads you see on TV during the day - Unity is copying the same approach, not doing anything more strict. Which is fair enough IMO - it's not like game ads are inherently more harmful than watching the TV.